# How to write a cookbook with external cookbook_files in Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

How do you create a general cookbook where you allow users to specify a location of a cookbook_file that will be copied? I'd imagine this file to be an overridable attribute.

For example: create an nginx cookbook where the user can specify where the SSL files are so that it can copy these files into the right directory in the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file should be in `files` subdirectory of the cookbook, if you want it to be accessible through `cookbook_file` resource. If you want to get the file from somewhere else, you need to use `remote_file`. (Do not set `node[:nginx][:ssl_file_location]` in your cookbook.)

```
cookbook_file filename do
  [...]
  only_if { node[:nginx][:ssl_file_location].nil? }
end

remote_file ::File.join( node[:nginx][:ssl_file_location].to_s, filename ) do
  [...]
  not_if { node[:nginx][:ssl_file_location].nil? }
end
```

When one needs to set ssl_file_location, he can create a attributes.json file:

```
{ "nginx": { "ssl_file_location" : "[my location]" } }
```

and run chef client:

```
chef-client --json-attributes attributes.json
```

**Edit:**

If ssh_files are actually in some other cookbook, then you can use cookbook_file, but you must provide cookbook attribute like that:

```
cookbook_file filename do
  [...]
  cookbook 'cookbook_name_where_to_look'
end
```

Comment: remote_file - thanks! Sounds like the key. Typically, would this be in some arbitrary folder of one's cookbook collection (the repo that has all the cookbooks and calls them for each role)?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question. [my location] can by any URI, including local path. So, you can store the files in arbitrary folder, but they must be accessible from the place you are running chef-client.

Comment: Great, thanks Draco! Yeah you understood my question. :) Will try it then accept when I get it working.

Comment: [Here's the error](https://gist.github.com/4405741) that chef shows me. It seems the problem is that `remote_file` prepends default locations to the `source`. You'll see in the link that it looks for `server.crt` in `files/ubuntu//tmp/chef-solo/.../server.crt`. Should `remote_file` only be used to get files over http? If there's no Chef resource for copying files outside a cookbook, perhaps I should just use the `bash` resource to do this?

Comment: It prepends default locations only if the uri is not absolute. Use `file:///var/lib/postgresql/9.2/main/server.crt`

Comment: Oh, ok thanks. It seems though that `remote_file` when used with non-http locations is deprecated now. Chef says we should use `cookbook_file` instead. However, if that's for files *inside* the cookbook, I'm not sure what else to use here.